# ElasticSearch Dynamic Method Injection Issues on Grails

Tags: grails, elasticsearch, grails-orm

I'm trying to make ElasticSearch 0.1.0 works with 2.4.4;

I have a lot of models with their default generate all GORM and i want to add a search Input to their index list, so i'm trying to accomplish this by injecting dynamic search method in my domain [Like DOCS says](http://noamt.github.io/elasticsearch-grails-plugin/docs/index.html#searching).

Here is my:

Config.groovy

```
elasticSearch {
    client.mode = 'local'
    datastoreImpl = 'hibernateDatastore'
}
```

Domain:

```
class Person implements Serializable {
    int PER_VALUE
    String PER_NAME
    String PER_CODE

    static searchable = true
}
```

Controller:

```
import org.grails.plugins.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchService
class PersonController {
    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "GET"]
    def elasticSearchService
    def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        println(Person.search("${params.query}").searchResults)
    }
```

The service i have, it's copy/paste from [HERE](https://github.com/noamt/elasticsearch-grails-plugin/tree/0.1.x/grails-app/services)

This is the error i'm getting:

> No signature of method: crud.userlist.Person.search() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values: [adsasd] Possible solutions: each(groovy.lang.Closure), attach(), merge(), refresh(), save(), merge(crud.userlist.Person)

Any help with this ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the [elasticsearch plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/elasticsearch)?

Comment: Yes, that's the one i'm using